# Mongoose doesn't save array with mixed type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Do I have to define an `errorMessages` subdocument to save an array with mixed types? (Also how would I do that then when I have to mix types inside that subdocument's array )

Just using an array results in not seeing any error messages, only an empty Array is visible. Using `mongoose.Mixed` as the type results in the string errors to be shown, but the error objects are left out.

Im a bit confused on how to achieve this

#### My Schema

[image: Schema]

#### My Document before saving

[image: Schema before save]

#### My Document after saving

[image: Schema after save]

#### Code

```js
// document is APIATicket
// error is either a string or an Error Object that has been created with new Error()
document.errorMessages.push(error);
document.save();

// other "normal" objects (created with object literals) result in the same behavior
const myObject = {msg: "Hello world"};
document.payload = myObject;
document.save();
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi edited

Comment: what is the issue? in your saved object, `errorMessages` is filled?

Comment: @japrescott `errorMessages` correctly saved the errors whose type is `string`. Entries in the `errorMessages` array that are of the type `object` do not get saved. Only an empty object is saved (as seen in the third picture, everything is expanded to the max)

Comment: @Twiggeh make sure to have written a toString and toJSON function on your Error object which returns a string representing your Error

Comment: @japrescott so I cannot save objects ?

Comment: @Twiggeh yes you can, but you need to generate a representation with toJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using `[Object]` is unnecessary, as it is equivalent to `[]`, which is an array of the [Mixed SchemaType](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed).
2. Mongoose doesn't (or at least in my case) save the default Node errors, which are created with `const nodeError = new Error("Error Message")`, but if the errors are destructured into a new Object `const newObject = {message: nodeError.message, stack: nodeError.stack}` and `newObject` gets pushed onto the errorMessages array, it will be saved as expected!